# Solving Friedmann equation for specific conditions

Tags: cosmology

In Friedman equation:

> the case k < 0, with a Universe containing only matter (pressure = 0)
>   so that $\rho = \rho_0/ a^3$ . What is the solution a(t) in a
>   situation where the final term of the Friedmann equation dominates
>   over the density term? How does the density of matter vary with time?

The question from an introduction to modern cosmology from Andrew Liddle.

Friedmann Equation:

$$(\dot {a}/a)^2 = 8\pi G \rho / 3 - k/a^2$$ 
My problem is I don't even understand the question? what does the first question mean? the answer of the book is $a(t) \alpha t$. I am not even sure that it is the only answer. Can anyone say what the question wants and is the answer of the book, the only answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wants to know what the general solution of the equation is in the circumstances given.

$$\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2 = \frac{8\pi G\rho}{3} - \frac{k}{a^2}$$
$$ \left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2 = \frac{8\pi G \rho_0}{a^3} - \frac{k}{a^2}$$

If the "second term dominates over the density term" (which it will when $a$ is large), then
$$ \dot{a} = -k$$
(but $k$ has a negative value)

Therefore $a(t) \propto t$.